# Text Sorting in Windows

Tags: windows, sorting, cmd

I have a text file which contains text in the following form

```
Name Surname: Group : Points
```

And i would like to know if its possible to sort by the highest points first.
I tried to use `sort /+pos file.txt` but it didnt work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS or are you referring to the command line in Windows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name command line in Windows, sorry my mistake.

Comment: Did you try typing `help sort` at the prompt?

Comment: @John Coleman yes and for options i get size and position.

Comment: `/R` reverses the sort order. `/+n` is based on character position -- not field position. Unless you know the exact column where `Points` begins this is a nonstarter. The natural solution is to write e.g. a brief VBScript script that splits on `:` and does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Windows sort only sorts text.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
If LCase(Arg(1)) = "n" then
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
        If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
            Set RE = new Regexp
            re.Pattern = "[^0-9\.,]"
            re.global = true
            re.ignorecase = true
            Sortkey = re.replace(Sortkey, "")
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
            Sortkey = 0
        ElseIf Sortkey = "" then
            Sortkey = 0
        ElseIf IsNull(Sortkey) = true then
            Sortkey = 0
        End If
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = CSng(SortKey)
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "d" then
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
        If IsDate(Sortkey) = False then
            Set RE = new Regexp
            re.Pattern = "[^0-9\\\-:]"
            re.global = true
            re.ignorecase = true
            Sortkey = re.replace(Sortkey, "")
        End If
        If IsDate(Sortkey) = False then
            Sortkey = 0
        ElseIf Sortkey = "" then
            Sortkey = 0
        ElseIf IsNull(Sortkey) = true then
            Sortkey = 0
        End If
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = CDate(SortKey)
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With


ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "tt" then
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Trim(Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3))))
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
End If
```

**Sort**

```
filter Sort {n|d|t|tt} {a|d} startcolumn  endcolumn
```

Sorts a file

```
n - extracts a number from the columns specified. Looks for the first number.
d - extracts a time or date from the columns specified. Looks for the first date.
t - extracts a text string including spaces from the columns specified.
tt - extracts a text string discarding leading and trailing spaces from the columns specified.

a - sorts acending
d - sorts decending
```

*startcolumn* - the starting column, the first character is column 1

*endcolumn* - the ending column

**Example**

```
cscript //nologo filter sort n a 1 11 < "%windir%\win.ini"
```

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```